# Simple HTML DOM Parser for microdata

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, microdata

I am using Simple HTML DOM parser to scrape data and ran into question: how to gather data contained in HTLM5 microdata.

For example, `<meta itemprop="title" content="Charlie and the Chocolate Factory">`

How would I get both the itemprop as well as the content for meta properties using Simple HTML DOM parser?

Comment: have you tried to use jquery to extract what you need? you can use `jquery(element).attr()`. Sample: `var item = $('meta[itemprop=Title]').attr('content');
console.log(item);`

Comment: I would prefer to use the same framework for all parsing.

Comment: If you cant use jquery then you can just stick with simple html dom parser. You can read it in the manual and its well documented anyways.

Comment: Does the following code, `$html->find('meta[itemprop]', 0);` and `html->find('meta[content]', 0);` work?

Answer (score 3):

Is the question how to iterate elements with an itemprop attribute? If so:

```
foreach($doc->find('[itemprop]') as $el){
  echo $el->itemprop . "\n";
  echo $el->content . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [**microdata-parser**](https://github.com/yusufkandemir/microdata-parser) which is a microdata parser library for PHP. You can feed it directly with HTML string or you can call `getDocument()` on Simple HTML Dom Parser instance to get `DomDocument` instance from it then feed `microdata-parser` with that, and get the output as array, object or as JSON.

Or if you want to reinvent the wheel yourself, you can take a look at [W3C's Microdata Specification - Converting microdata to JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#json)(could be a PHP array or an object if you don't convert it to JSON). Simply looking for `itemprop` attributes might not the best solution if you want all the things with correct structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [MicrodataPHP](https://github.com/linclark/MicrodataPHP). I haven't been keeping up with changes in the spec, but it should cover your use case, and you can file issues if something is out of line with the current spec.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to do it is using a switch statement for every itemprop element on the page.

eg:

```
foreach($html->find('[itemprop]') as $productDetail){
    switch ($productDetail->itemprop) {
        case 'image':
            $line['imageURL'] = $productDetail->src;
            break;
        case 'price':
            $line['price'] =  $productDetail->plaintext; //note: plaintext not content
            break;
        case 'name':
            $line['name'] =  $productDetail->plaintext;
            break;
        case 'productId':
            $line['productId'] =  $productDetail->content;
            break;
        case 'description':
            $line['description'] =  $productDetail->content;
            break;
        case 'url':
            $line['url'] =  $productDetail->content;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using parser for this job? Use the php function below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

```
get_meta_tags("url");
```

Comment: microdata != metadata. Microdata may be represented using `<meta>`, but also using other tags. Plus, `get_meta_tags()` stops parsing at `</head>`, while microdata typically appear in the body.